# Making a change in a module then reloading it

Tags: python, wxpython

I am adjusting the wxPython DragImage demo, and I have a main file that i execute which imports the DragImage demo... I want to make changes to the DragImage demo then reload the file, to view the changes. For example, i want to insert something in a list on the DragImage, then save the DragImage, then when reloading it on my main file the changes appear... how can that happen please help me my project is due in 8 hrs...

Comment: Hint:  Use Search.  http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpython%5D+reload+module

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I unload (reload) a Python module?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/437589/how-do-i-unload-reload-a-python-module)

Answer (score 0):

Use the builtin function `reload(modulename)`

Comment: but it resets everything to original